# Como pegar valores de formulários POST no Django usando Class Based View

Tags: html, python, django, post, django-templates

Tenho um formulário bem simples e preciso pegar o valor de um input:

```
    <form method="POST">
        <label>Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_name" />
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
```

Minha classe da view está assim:

```
class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home/index.html"
```

Como eu pego o valor do input? Obs: Preciso usar obrigatoriamente o Class Based View.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

Para este caso, você deverá utilizar um FormView.

Crie dentro do app um arquivo chamado forms.py, e dentro dele crie o seguinte código:

from django import forms

```
class MeuForm(forms.Form):

    user_name = forms.CharField(label='Nome')
```

Faça o import do form dentro da sua view assim:

from .forms import MeuForm

E modifique sua view do seguinte modo:

```
class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home/index.html"
    form_class = MeuForm
    success_url = 'url_para_onde_direcionar_apos_o_submit'
```

Com isso já será possível fazer com que o form funcione. Agora, para pegar esses dados e fazer alguma tratativa com os mesmos, basta sobrescrever o método "form_valid" dentro da sua View, ficaria assim:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    # aqui você faz o que deseja com os dados
    # e no fim retorna o form para que o submit ocorra.
    return super().form_valid(form)
```